# automated script to install python package over a proxy?

Tags: python, automation

Would it be possible to write a little Python script that would automatically install a needed Python library import if the needed library wasn't already installed?

Currently I am using

```
try:
    import xlrd #Library to iterate through excel docs
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('XLRD not installed, use "sudo pip install xlrd"\n')
```

but would like something more automated.

Comment: Why don't you distribute your program with a `setup.py`/`requirements.txt`?

Comment: How do I have them install all the requirements easily?

Comment: pip install -r requirements.txt ?

Comment: Or `python setup.py install` (which installs both your library and any requirements) if you go with the former.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments the setup.py approach is a good one and quite easy.

Beyond that if you need to install dependencies across multiple servers I suggest you have a look at solution like http://www.ansible.com/home or https://puppetlabs.com/

As a one-off you can do that too:

```
ssh user@yourserver.com 'pip install xlrd'
```

**Edit** - Following up on the comments:

Once you have created you setup.py specifying the dependency on xlrd you have to run it on every machine where you want to install your app. In order to do that checkout the automation tool I advised above.

You could also do that but that's really dirty:

```
try:
    import xlrd #Library to iterate through excel docs
except ImportError:
    from subprocess import call

    call(["pip", "install", "xlrd"])
```

Comment: can install_requires in setup.py not take in proxy settings?

Comment: or how can I have it install through locally?

Comment: ah right on. So if the actual directory of the package lives locally within the directory, but it's not installed on the system, would pip be necessary

Comment: or does pip go and grab that local directory and install it there

Comment: pip will install the package for the whole system, unless you are running it in a virtualenv or anaconda virtual env